# Android: Saving ArrayList of User Defined Objects between onPause and onResume

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application where i am saving the state of an application in an ArrayList. Now, to save this state, i tried to use Serialization. But, somewhere in the user defined object, i am using Button, which is not letting me serialize the entire object.

I wanted to know, is there any other way of saving this array list between onPause and onResume?. I even tried onSaveInstanceState, but it doesnt have support for ArrayList.

Thanks,
Chander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, somewhere in the user defined object, i am using Button

Never mix your models and views. Please redesign your "state" to be pure model data.

> I wanted to know, is there any other way of saving this array list between onPause and onResume?

If it involves widgets like `Button`, then no.

Once you clean up your state, you can persist it to a database, or persist it to a JSON/XML file, or serialize it to a file, or whatever.

`onSaveInstanceState()` is solely for transient data, such as the contents of an `EditText`. Do not confuse this with the business data (model) for your application.